# Jquery selector that does not include and node(or its children) with specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element (div) that has a class also found in its children. I need a selector that finds the main element and all of its children but does not include any children with the same class (or its children).

I need a selector that gives me the root, plus any descendants that don’t also have the “child” class.

```html
<div class="foo child">
  <div class="foo child">
    I don’t want this or any child.
    <div class="foo">
      I don’t want this either.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
   I do want this and any children.
  </div>
</div>
```

I’ve tried various attempts at :not but haven’t found one that works.

Specific reason. I’m using jquery.resizable and the element I am resizing is a group that contains some children elements that also have the class “resizable”. When resizing the parent, I don’t want to resize the children at the same time - which is what is happening because the class exists in the children also.

TIA,
Will

Comment: A specific example of the HTML structure and what you want to select from it would probably clarify things, it's a lot easier to debug concrete code

Comment: Well, posting from a phone and the html example I included  got deleted from the body...

Comment: Do the ones you are interested in always contain elements with the same class?

Comment: Yes. Odd, seems when I view this on my PC, the <div> is included. Yes, see the div in the main post. I want everything except for any children (or their descendants) where the child also has the class "child".

Comment: You want the top-level `foo child` DIV?

Comment: Which is the class that identifies the top-level element, `foo` or `child`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".foo:not(.foo .foo.child,.foo .foo.child *)")
```

`.foo` matches all `class="foo"`. `.foo .foo.child` matches any `class="foo child"` that's contained in another `class="foo"`, and `.foo .foo.child *` matches all of its descendants.

Comment: I'm not sure we can assume there will be this `foo` class.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation put me on the right path for the exact selector I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way than to `filter` out the ones that have a `.child` ancestor from all the `.child` and `.child` descendants.

```js
$( '.child, .child *' ) // all .child and their descendants
  .filter( (i,el) =>
    // remove the .child that have a .child parent (".child .child")
    // and their descendants (".child .child *")
    !$( el ).is( '.child .child, .child .child *' )
  )
  .addClass( 'green' );
```

```css
* { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo child">
  <div class="foo child">
    I don’t want this or any child.
    <div class="foo">
      I don’t want this either.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
   I do want this and <span>any children.</span>
  </div>
  And even this
</div>
```

And since it's apparently to be used in a resize event, in your position I would save this selection in a reusable variable, so that it hasn't to performed too many times.